# ChangeFeed disconnected

Tags: rethinkdb

I'm running 3 shard setup on ComposeIO accessed via HTTP proxy.

My server is NodeJS using the latest version (2.2.2) of official RethinkDB driver (http://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/)

The changes feed fails with message `Changefeed aborted (unavailable).`

RethinkDB documentation states "If the table becomes unavailable, the changefeed will be disconnected, and a runtime exception will be thrown by the driver." but offers no advice on how to prevent/recover.

Answer (score 1):

The table should only become unavailable if there are connectivity problems in the cluster or you're reconfiguring it.  If it's the former, you should contact Compose and see if they can figure out why the cluster is having connectivity problems.  If you're reconfiguring the table frequently, the best thing to do would be to try and rework things so that you don't have to.

As for recovering when that does happen, the only thing to do really is to restart the changefeed.

Comment: Thanks. I have put in a request to Compose so hopefully it is a configuration issue. The Compose dashboard does show all servers and proxy as "healthy", nothing in logs, so a mystery at the moment.

Comment: ComposeIO advised that they set a timeout of 1 hour on changes feed. Since I'm developing my application does not have a high level of activity and consequently can easily exceed this timeout. I did not get any advice on how to reconnect so will look into that next.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that if the RethinkDB changes feed fails for any reason the web socket connection will fail and no notification sent to clients even if the changes feed is reconnected.

The solution is to restart the socket connection on the first request after the failure.

Call `restartLiveUpdates()` before any API call (ideally use an interceptor to call it on all applicable requests) to restart the socket if required.

```js
// setup express and socketIO
const app = express();
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIO(httpServer);
// socketIO connection
eventService.liveUpdates(io);
// serve
httpServer.listen(port);


let restart = false;
let socket;


function connect() {
  return r.connect(config.get('rethinkdb'));
}


export function liveUpdates(io) {
  // store io ref for restarting connection
  if (io && !socket) {
    socket = io;
  }
  console.log('Setting up listener...');
  // so we can close connection on error
  let conn;
  connect().then((c) => {
    conn = c;
    r.table('pulses')
    .changes()
    .run(conn)
    .then((cursor) => {
      console.log('Listening for changes...');
      cursor.each((err, change) => {
        if (err) {
          restart = true;
          if (conn) {
            console.log('Close changes connection');
            conn.close();
          }
        } else {
          restart = false;
          socket.emit('event-change', change);
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
  

// restart changes feed if it has timed out
function restartLiveUpdates() {
  if (restart) {
    // set false immediately so we do not get multiple restarts due to different client requests
    restart = false;
    liveUpdates();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for elaborating about this issue which I faced frequently with my deployment on Modulus and Compose. You got me in the right direction!